# Desired capabilities isjavascriptenabled deprecated. How can we use the java script enabled in Internet explorer driver selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The method isJavascriptEnabled is deprecated. How can we use the javascript enabled feature in selenium. Can you please help in finding an alternative method for the same?

[image]

Comment: In your snippet `dc.isJavascriptEnabled();` does nothing, you neither set the value nor you use the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you work with *Selenium Java Client v3.14.0*:

- To explicitly *enable* **javascript** you can use an instance of **DesiredCapabalities** class as follows:

  ```
  capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
  ```
- To explicitly *disable* **javascript** you can use an instance of **DesiredCapabalities** class as follows:

  ```
  capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(false);
  ```

---

### Update

As per @JimEvans comment:

> In case of IE, even if you request **`setJavascriptEnabled(false)`**, you won’t get it. The IE driver requires *JavaScript* to be **enabled**, and it will always be enabled in the browser instance created by the driver. There is no option; there is no workaround.

Comment: I should point out that in the case of IE, even if you request `setJavascriptEnabled(false)`, you won’t get it. The IE driver requires JavaScript to be enabled, and it will always be enabled in the browser instance created by the driver. There is no option; there is no workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    ieCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    InternetExplorerOptions opt = new InternetExplorerOptions(ieCapabilities);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
          "./src/test/resources/drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
```